# When to use expect.stringContaining instead of toContain for substring matching in Jest

Tags: jestjs

What's the use case to use `stringContaining` instead of just using `toContain` for substring matching with Jest?

```
it("tests with stringContaining", () => {
  expect("testerama").toEqual(expect.stringContaining("test"))
})
it("tests with toContain", () => {
  expect("testerama").toContain("test")
})
```

As far as I can see the behaviour is similar apart from that if the string is `null` or `undefined` the `stringContaining` error message is a bit clearer.

```
Expected: StringContaining "test"
Received: null
```

as opposed to

```
Matcher error: received value must not be null nor undefined
Received has value: null
```

It hardly seems worth it for the less terse code. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess an advantage of `stringContaining` is it'll fail for an *array*, so it's slightly more specific and therefore safer if what you expect is actually a substring, whereas `toContain` does double duty. It's less readable IMO, though.

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference is that the `expect.stringContaining` method is maintained by the community, whereas `expect.toContain` is part of the official Jest API.